# Does random forest give the option to fix the number of splits in Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, decision-tree

I am using Treebagger in Matlab but I couldn't find the option to fix the number of splits. Is there any way I can fix the maximum number of splits when using Treebagger?

Comment: https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitrtree.html#bt6cr84-MaxNumSplits ? (treebagger inherits this from fit(c/r)tree)